# Xamarin.Forms and Firebase - IDocumentSnapshot disposed half way through for loop

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

## Scenario

I have a Xamarin.Forms application with multiple pages. I'm using the `Plugin.CloudFirestore` wrapper for `Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore` and `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Firestore` by f-miyu on GitHub:

https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore

## Problem

Okay, so I began with this script:

```
foreach (IDocumentSnapshot row in postArray.Documents)
{

}
```

Which only worked on the odd occasion, throwing the error:
`System.ArgumentException: 'Handle must be valid. Parameter name: instance'`

I noticed it also worked when I disabled other awaited asynchronous calls within the loop. I saw in an issue on Github a possible fix using `.ToList()` which somewhat worked and slightly reduced the amount of times the loop throws an error:

```
foreach (IDocumentSnapshot row in postArray.Documents.ToList())
{

}
```

However, the new error I am receiving is different and happens when awaited async calls take a long time to complete within the loop (IE: the ones that download image and other file data from firebase):

**`System.ObjectDisposedException`**

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Firebase.Firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot'
```

The `postArray` variable is a member of the page class:

```
public partial class ProfileView : ContentPage
{
        IQuerySnapshot postArray;
}
```

And is set through a method called `GetPostsAsync`:

```
async Task GetPostsAsync(IDocumentSnapshot startPage = null)
{
            postArray = await postHandle.ListUserPosts(userID, startPage);

            if(startPage == null)
            {
                recentPostArray = postArray;
            }
}
```

The method `ListUserPosts` simply builds a Firestore query and returns the result of the `.GetAsync()` method.
The resulting `postArray` is then accessed from a function called `DisplayPosts()` which includes the above loop

I have no idea why the garbage collecting service is disposing of the IDocumentSnapshot before the loop has finished and am certain that the two errors are caused by the same thing. I have had similar errors before whilst developing which have all ironed themselves out some way or another but this one has me completely stuck. I fear that when rolled out, the application will crash if users have too many posts to display on their pages as when removing certain async calls (like downloading an image for example), the error disappears. The error also doesn't appear when one image post is displayed and less than three other posts - when a third post is introduced alongside the image post, the error reappears. As many regular posts as I wish can be loaded but as soon as one is introduced that has an image attached to it, the app has a chance of crashing.

Comment: How is IDocumentSnapshot called? May this GitHub issue be related?
 
https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore/issues/56

Comment: @DamPlz `IQuerySnapshot postArray = postsRef.WhereEqualsTo("authorID", userID).OrderBy("time_stamp", true).LimitTo(8).GetAsync();` is the query that is built. It's documents are then iterated over as shown above to produce each `IDocumentSnapshot row` that are used within the loop

Comment: Is it convenient to show more code or leave your complete project for testing?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm building this for a client and so some elements of the full project must remain strictly confidential

Comment: I need to reproduce your problem before resolving it. Would you like to provide some code that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: The problem only persists when multiple firebase requests are happening at once. I have solved it temporarily by reverting to the old version of the garbage collector on android with a compiler argument. The problem doesn't exist at all on iOS